# Blocking chat in gmail website with SonicWALL TZ 180 Enhanced OS

Tags: security, firewall, gateway, sonicwall, instant-messaging

We have a SonicWALL TZ 180 with Enhanced OS.

We want to block the chat web app within gmail's site, but not block the whole gmail site.

I've turned IPS on, and all IM to prevent.

Any ideas?

I've seen some post about editing the local computer host file, but I'd prefer to do it at the gateway level.

Thanks!

[alt text http://web1.twitpic.com/img/63945705-b374cb9908dd94bd6c2ee4ef56d79af6.4b7029f8-scaled.png](http://web1.twitpic.com/img/63945705-b374cb9908dd94bd6c2ee4ef56d79af6.4b7029f8-scaled.png)

[alt text http://web2.twitpic.com/img/63945662-8e969d7dab3b513ca96108af566600f2.4b702a4d-full.png](http://web2.twitpic.com/img/63945662-8e969d7dab3b513ca96108af566600f2.4b702a4d-full.png)

[alt text http://web7.twitpic.com/img/63945619-27f6ce6a28dcfdd46daa21cd0e91243b.4b702a60-full.png](http://web7.twitpic.com/img/63945619-27f6ce6a28dcfdd46daa21cd0e91243b.4b702a60-full.png)

Comment: added pics so you guys can eval settings....

Answer (score 1):

I googled and found:

> google have deliberately setup gmail with a way to allow companies to block just chat. All they need to do is to block **chatenabled.mail.google.com** and google chat won't work. Using a https session won't help as gmail will still check that it has acces through this URL before proceeding.

Looks like all you have to do is to simply block a URL.

Comment: I can do that at the local level by pointing chatenabled.mail.google.com to 127.0.0.1, that works. Still running into issues blocking it with sonicwall's CFS, network wide. I have it blocked there under forbidden domains, but the app is still running.

Comment: Do you have CFS enabled? I know it sounds like a simple question but it needs to be turned on under the Network->Zones page.

Comment: Good question, but it's on for the LAN